# Javascript toFixed() is not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I am using `toFixed` but the method does not operate as expected

```
parseFloat(19373.315).toFixed(2);

//19373.31   Chrome
```

**Expected Output : 19373.32**

```
parseFloat(9373.315).toFixed(2);
// 9373.32  Working fine
```

Why does the first example round down, whereas the second example round up?

Comment: is floating point math broken?

Comment: [Try this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832950/2569323) `toFixed` is browser-dependend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566564/math-roundnum-vs-num-tofixed0-and-browser-inconsistencies.

Comment: @AjAX. this one is also giving 19373.31

Comment: @JaromandaX : sorry, i didn't get your point

Comment: Indeed. Strange…

Comment: @HituBansal What he is saying is, floating point math won't work as you expect it to work everywhere. Because, how you represent floating point might vary from one system to another. So, this is no wonder..

Comment: I was alluding to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: refer to vahid's answer. javascript has stupidities like this. round it yourself before fixing, if its very important.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that binary floating point representation of most decimal fractions is not exact. The internal representation of 19373.315 may actually be something like 19373.314999999, so toFixed rounds down, while 19373.315 might be 19373.315000001, which rounds up.

Comment: Assuming toFixed casts to 32-bit float; https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html
 19373.315 -> 19373.314453125 (error of -0.000546875)

Comment: This is despite `(19373.315).toFixed(4)` = 19373.3150 ... Even if this is "expected" or "intended", I'd still report it as a bug. Should use a double and proper rounding during conversion to fixed string. I think the spec even says so. :\

Comment: I consolidated my comments and research into an answer and provided a "fixed" workaround.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the first example round down, whereas the second example round up?

Look at the binary representation of the two values in memory.

```js
const farr = new Float64Array(2);
farr[0] = 19373.315;
farr[1] = 9373.315;
const uarr = new Uint32Array(farr.buffer);
console.log(farr[0], uarr[1].toString(2).padStart(32, 0) + uarr[0].toString(2).padStart(32, 0));
console.log(farr[1], uarr[3].toString(2).padStart(32, 0) + uarr[2].toString(2).padStart(32, 0));
```

Without diving into the details, we can see that the second value has an additional '1' at the end, which is lost in the first larger value when it is fit into 64 bits.

Comment: Yet `(19373.315).toFixed(4)` yields `19373.3150`.
 The 1 at the end is why `(19373.3150).toFixed(39)` yields `19373.314999999998690327629446983337402343750`... Pretty sure there's a bug here where toFixed has a missed rounding case.

Comment: @TylerY86 Gee, that reminds me of [another Chrome bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602799), now luckily fixed.

Comment: I think that bug is a significant order of magnitude (-0.998) worse in precision than this (-.000000000002) though. It still comes out `0.0022002200220022002200220022002201` though. lol

Comment: Perhaps the spec might have been to specific with instructions for the toFixed function and included a bug? (FF does this too.) lol

Comment: ^-0.998 should be 0.098

Comment: Wait, that's toString... `0.0022002200220022002200220022002201` is roughly correct in base 3?

Comment: @TylerY86 Yes, this was eventually fixed in some release of V8 and now `toString` seems to work well again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming toFixed casts to 32-bit float;
[Check with this utility...](https://h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

19373.315 is stored as 19373.314453125 (an error of -0.000546875) in 32-bit floating point format.

This is despite `(19373.315).toFixed(4)` coming out as `19373.3150`.

Even if this is "expected" or "intended", I'd still report it as a bug.

It should use a double during the rounding check, and thus proper rounding during conversion to fixed string.

I think the spec even says so. :\

In the V8 javascript engine source, the `Number.prototype.toFixed` function invokes `DoubleToFixedCString` in [this file](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/conversions.cc#L1030) ...

There's probably some inappropriate optimization in there... (Looking into it.)

I'd suggest submitting an [additional test case for V8](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/test/webkit/fast/js/number-tofixed.js) with 19373.315 specifically.

`(19373.3150).toFixed(39)` yields 19373.314999999998690327629446983337402343750.

Rounding occurs once to bring it up to 19373.315 - which is correct - but not at the right digit when rounding to 2 digits.

I think this should have a second pass on rounding here to catch edge cases like this. I think it might have to round to `n+1` digits, then again to `n` digits. Maybe there's some other clever way to fix it though.

```js
function toFixedFixed(a,n) {
  return (a|0) + parseFloat((a % 1).toFixed(n+1)).toFixed(n).substr(1);
}

console.log(toFixedFixed(19373.315,2)); // "19373.32"
console.log(toFixedFixed(19373.315,3)); // "19373.315"
console.log(toFixedFixed(19373.315,4)); // "19373.3150"
console.log(toFixedFixed(19373.315,37)); // "19373.3149999999986903276294469833374023438"
console.log(toFixedFixed(19373.315,38)); // "19373.31499999999869032762944698333740234375"
console.log(toFixedFixed(19373.315,39)); // "19373.314999999998690327629446983337402343750"
```

(Adopted from my comments on Vahid Rahmani's answer, who is correct.)

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have explained why, I would suggest using a library like [numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) which will round things as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

```
export const preciseRound = (value, exp) => {
  /**
   * Decimal adjustment of a number.
   *
   * @param   {String}    type    The type of adjustment.
   * @param   {Number}    value   The number.
   * @param   {Integer}   exp     The exponent (the 10 logarithm of the adjustment base).
   * @returns {Number}            The adjusted value.
   */
  function decimalAdjust(type, value, exp) {
    // If the exp is undefined or zero...
    if (typeof exp === "undefined" || +exp === 0) {
      return Math[type](value);
    }
    value = +value;
    exp = +exp;
    // If the value is not a number or the exp is not an integer...
    if (isNaN(value) || !(typeof exp === "number" && exp % 1 === 0)) {
      return NaN;
    }
    // Shift
    value = value.toString().split("e");
    value = Math[type](+(value[0] + "e" + (value[1] ? +value[1] - exp : -exp)));
    // Shift back
    value = value.toString().split("e");
    return +(value[0] + "e" + (value[1] ? +value[1] + exp : exp));
  }

  // You can use floor, ceil or round
  return decimalAdjust("round", value, exp);
};
```

```
console.log(preciseRound(1.005, -2));  // <= 1.01
console.log(preciseRound(1.341, -2));  // <= 1.34
console.log(preciseRound(1.01, -2));   // <= 1.01
console.log(preciseRound(33.355, -2)); // <= 33.36
```